# Benchmark of provisionning delays of various cloud providers

Tags: virtual-machines, boot, cloud-computing, latency, cloud-hosting

Cloud computing supposedly lets you instantiate on-demand processing power through additional VMs. The allocation process is frequently advertised as *fast* without further details. My personal experience is that VM instantiations on various cloud providers takes anywhere from 10s to 2h.

Since cloud computing providers are charge VMs per hour, I would be very interested in a comparison of VM start latency (from provisioning request, to client app being executed):

- Amazon EC2: ?
- Windows Azure: ?
- Rackspace Cloud: ?
- *add yours here*

What is the typically observed latency on favorite cloud provider?

Answer (score 1):

I only have real experience with Rackspace Cloud, but it's seconds/minutes there.